# Переднее и заднее стёкла были разбиты? Или стекло?

Tags: грамотная-речь, синтаксис

Помогите разобраться: Переднее и заднее стекло (или стёкла) были разбиты(-о)? Как правильно написать?

Comment: Спасибо большое за поправку вопроса... Надеюсь, в скором времени помогут)

Comment: Стекла. Нет причин использовать единственное число.

Comment: Niemand, спасибо вам большое...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Переднее и заднее  стёкла были разбиты.*

Розенталь рекомендует ставить существительное в форме множ. числа, если подчёркивается наличие нескольких предметов, а в данном примере говорится о том, что разбиты **два стекла**.

Comment: Людмила, я вам очень - очень благодарна...